# How to save and load a Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loading, save

So I am creating a program which will keep track of the TV shows and Movies that I watch. I have 2 classes (TV and Movie) and I have an Array which holds everyone. How would i go about saving this array so that every time I use the program it lets me edit the same list, because every time I watch a new episode I want to update my array with the new information. So basically what procedure would I need to use in order to not only save an arrya but load up the array every time I run the program?

Comment: load the array from a database/disk store or elsewhere?

Comment: I would want to store it on a local disk. But I have never used a database, so is there a way to just reload an array? Or will I have to use some type of database?

Comment: While object serialisation will work, I would, if you can avoid it.  It does not handle changes to the underlying objects (say you want to add a rating field to you objects, you'd lose all the stored data).  I'd err on the side of caution and use an XML format or even a plain file format if you don't like XML.

Answer (score 3):

In order to save an array for further reference you need to make the class serializable (for example, by implementing [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)). What this means is that an object can be converted to a sequence of bytes which could be saved to a file or sent over the network, which can later be used to recreate the object in memory

Then you can do this to save the data to a file:

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream("myarray.ser")
);
out.writeObject(myArray);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

You can read it back like this:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myarray.ser"));
MyType[] array = (MyType[]) in.readObject();
in.close();
```

Comment: I think it would be worth including a short summary of what being Serializable means.

Comment: @gobernador No need, because God invented javadoc

Comment: @Bohemian 99% of the time, I completely agree, although I have to say that in this particular case, the javadoc for [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) is a bit difficult to understand unless you already understand the concept.

Comment: This would work for custom objects too, right? (As long as you declare them as implementing Serializable?) Or only 1d arrays?

Comment: @KalamariKing The same technique works for `Serializable` objects of custom types. Of course you need to adjust the type conversion on line two of the last code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

While you could serialize your object and write it to disk... I am guessing it would be easier for you to simply output your array to a file and read it back in. You can write each element in the array to the file in a loop fairly easily, and read it back in just as easily. And like the others said, it is worth your time to look into an ArrayList or similar structure! Example:

To write to a file:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// add stuff the the ArrayList

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt")));

for( int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
{
out.println(list.get(x));
}

out.close()
```

To read from a file:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

while(scan.hasNext())
{
list.add(scan.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should avoid arrays like the plague... use `Collections` instead, which apart from anything else expand in size automatically as needed (you'll need this).

Regardless of whether you use array or a `List` you can serialize the object to disk by writing the object to an `ObjectOutputStream` wrapping a `FileOutputStream`.

Note that the objects *in* the array/List must implement `Serializable`, as must all your class fields.

To read the array/List back in, read from an `ObjectInputStream` wrapping a `FileInputStream`.

You can Google for the countless examples of such code.

Comment: "Firstly, you should avoid arrays like the plague... use Collections instead, which apart from anything else expand in size automatically as needed (you'll need this)."

In this particular case, a Collection would be more useful. That does NOT mean anyone should "avoid arrays like the plague". Each method of storing data has its benefits, or they wouldn't exist, immutables included.