# Save diffrent kind of variables to a file

Tags: java, file, read-write

I want to save diffrent kind of variables to a file. Currently I am using `DataOutputStream` to do so. First i save an array of shorts, then i save another array of shorts, then i want to save an array of longs. The problem is when i read the file, I dont know how many shorts i saved. I dont know how big the first short array is.

I could solve this by specifying a value that let me know when the short array stops. For example i say the value -99999 tells me when the array ended. But there is a small chance the short array contains the value -99999 before it ended.

Is there a way to create marks? Or should I create diffrent files for each array?

Comment: Well, if it's only numbers that you need to delimit, I'd argue that a good bet for a delimiter would be a letter.

Comment: @Alex Yes this solves my problem, lol. Thanks, sorry for the stupid question :), post your comment as answer then i can close this, or should i just delete the question?

Comment: Why don't you save that in an easy to parse, standard format like JSON or XML, rather than inventing your own format?

Comment: @JB Nizet, using xml would take longer to save and the file would be bigger, right?

Comment: @Alexanus So use JSON!

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, i dont know what it is, but i will read about it.

Comment: Yes, XML is more verbose. JSON is more compact. There are libraries that allow saving in binary format if compactness is such an important feature. But I would choose something simple and easy to read.

Comment: Why bother with xml or json or anything if just a text file is suitable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save and load a Array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661376/how-to-save-and-load-a-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the length of the array first, then read that many elements

Answer (score 2):

**You should first write the array length followed by the array**, in such way you will know how many items to read.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

Writing:

```
short[] shorts1 = ...; //an array
short[] shorts2 = ...; //another array
long[] longs = ...; //another array
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("the filename"))) {
    out.writeObject(shorts1);
    out.writeObject(shorts2);
    out.writeObject(longs);
    out.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code first writes two separate short arrays to a file, and after that one long array.

Reading:

```
short[] shorts1;
short[] shorts2;
long[] longs;
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("the filename"))) {
    shorts1 = (short[])in.readObject();
    shorts2 = (short[])in.readObject();
    longs = (long[])in.readObject();
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code reads the two separate short arrays and the long array from the file to which they're written.

Comment: @jenzz Yes it does, use ObjectOutputStream.writeObject (someArray)

Comment: Please add an explanation for why this solves the OP's problem, which had to do with reading, not writing, objects.

Comment: I clarified my answer

Comment: Er, no, you didn't. You just gave code, rather than explaining how this answers the question at all.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The two short arrays are separated, aren't they?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with anything I said.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Alexanus wants to know how to write two separate short arrays to a file (he wants to know when the first array stops and when the second begins, doesn't he?)

Comment: So explain -- in your answer, since it's a vital part -- how your code does that.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I provided a tiny explanation. Do you understand now? Otherwise I think I don't get you.